# Cross platform chat program with local log?

Tags: windows, android, linux, chat

It seems Skype for Linux is no longer a desktop app but some resource hog desktop app layer thrown over the Skype for Web client and as such it is no longer capable of local logging. There's a 30 day log but that's on Microsoft's computers (I refuse to call other companies computers the "cloud") and not mine. And I need more than 30 days anyways.

So, is there a chat program which is available cross platform (Windows, Android, Linux at least) and logs?

Answer (score 1):

Pidgin is a chat program which lets you log in to accounts on multiple chat networks simultaneously. This means that you can be chatting with friends on MSN, talking to a friend on Google Talk, and sitting in a Yahoo chat room all at the same time.

https://www.pidgin.im

**Is it crossplatform:** Pidgin runs on Windows, Linux, and other UNIX operating systems. Looking for Pidgin for OS X? [Try Adium](https://adium.im/)!

**Does it have infinite log support:** Well I guess so.

**Does it have local log support:** Yes.

Note: I tried to connect to MSN with this program and many others however couldn't accomplish what I want. But I believe this software can be used for chatting purposes.